# What is a proper "Connection String" for my C# app?

Tags: c#, connection-string, sql-server-express, localdb

The word is, I would like to run my C# app on a computer with Windows XP and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed. Although I tried any possible connection strings, I could not run my App on that computer. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I tried these connections strings:

```
Data Source=(local); integrated security=SSPI; database=SepidarDatabase.mdf

server=.\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=SSPI;database=SepidarDatabase.mdf

"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;SepidarDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"   
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

They all throw an exception error:

> Invalid Value Key for "attachDbFileName"!

Comment: It depends from your Instance Name, Database and security. Show what have you tried and what error messages you get.

Comment: what's the error? you can use http://www.connectionstrings.com to generate `Connection String`

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I added some useful information to my question.

Comment: database name should be the logical name, not the physical file name

Comment: I modified the string as you kindly said, but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="LPSConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Your-Data-Source;Initial Catalog=Database-Name;Uid=Your-User-Id;pwd=Your-Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect TimeOut=600;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Add this into your app.config file.it is working for me perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added the following connection string according to your reply but it didn't work. Note that since I use windows authentication, I replaced "integrated security=SSPI" instead of Uid and pwd.  
  

    '<add name="LPSConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SepidarDatabase.mdf;integrated security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect TimeOut=600;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>'

Comment: Try setting Integrated Security=true, sometimes this also works@user3913217

Comment: Sorry... I am new to StachOverFlow; So I'm not so familiar how to format my comments just like yours.

Comment: that's not the problem @user3913217

Comment: Oh, i think you should use AttachDbFilename instead of Initial Catalog. and have to give physical path instead of file name @user3913217

Comment: Dear @yash, I have already attached my DB by using SQL management studio, so I don't think I need to attach it again.